# Mapquest API Route Matrix time and day options do nothing

Tags: json, post, directions, mapquest

I am writing a simple application in Java to get time and drive distance data from the MapQuest API using their Route Matrix. I can get regular data just fine, but it appears that the date and time parameters (explained [here](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/directions-api/routetime-refresh/)) do not change anything.

My two request bodies are:

```
{"locations": ["55455","55113"],"options": {"allToAll": true,
"dateType": 0,"date": "12/17/2016","timeType": 2,"localTime": "12:00"}}
```

and

```
{"locations": ["55455","55113"],"options": {"allToAll": true,
"dateType": 0,"date": "12/13/2016","timeType": 2,"localTime": "16:30"}}
```

I get the same response for both requests:

```
{
  "allToAll": true,
  "time": [
    [
      0,
      573
    ],
    [
      562,
      0
    ]
  ],
  "distance": [
    [
      0,
      7.485
    ],
    [
      6.764,
      0
    ]
  ],
  "locations": [
    {
      "latLng": {
        "lng": -93.234543,
        "lat": 44.975052
      },
      "adminArea4": "Hennepin County",
      "adminArea5Type": "City",
      "adminArea4Type": "County",
      "adminArea5": "Minneapolis",
      "street": "",
      "adminArea1": "US",
      "adminArea3": "MN",
      "type": "s",
      "displayLatLng": {
        "lng": -93.234543,
        "lat": 44.975052
      },
      "linkId": 286290952,
      "postalCode": "55455",
      "dragPoint": false,
      "sideOfStreet": "N",
      "adminArea1Type": "Country",
      "geocodeQuality": "ZIP",
      "geocodeQualityCode": "Z1XAA",
      "adminArea3Type": "State"
    },
    {
      "latLng": {
        "lng": -93.15676,
        "lat": 45.012234
      },
      "adminArea4": "Ramsey County",
      "adminArea5Type": "City",
      "adminArea4Type": "County",
      "adminArea5": "St Paul",
      "street": "",
      "adminArea1": "US",
      "adminArea3": "MN",
      "type": "s",
      "displayLatLng": {
        "lng": -93.15676,
        "lat": 45.012234
      },
      "linkId": 286290770,
      "postalCode": "55113",
      "dragPoint": false,
      "sideOfStreet": "N",
      "adminArea1Type": "Country",
      "geocodeQuality": "ZIP",
      "geocodeQualityCode": "Z1XAA",
      "adminArea3Type": "State"
    }
  ],
  "manyToOne": false,
  "info": {
    "copyright": {
      "text": "Â© 2016 MapQuest, Inc.",
      "imageUrl": "http://api.mqcdn.com/res/mqlogo.gif",
      "imageAltText": "Â© 2016 MapQuest, Inc."
    },
    "statuscode": 0,
    "messages": []
  }
}
```

So for some reason, Saturday at noon has the same travel times as Tuesday at 16:30. Is there something wrong with my request, or does MapQuest not actually have this capability for the Route Matrix? The API documentation leads me to believe that the date/time options should work on any package in the Directions  API, so could someone clear this up? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I've made sure to try a route that I know for sure has HOV lanes that are restricted during the rush hour and not on the Saturday. I also tried enabling MapQuest's `useTraffic` parameter. Neither of these had any effect on the data. MapQuest states that `useTraffic` depends on availability of information, so I think I can only assume that it can't find information (which is strange, since I know that there is tons of data for this area). If anyone has any other ideas or explanations I'd be happy to hear.

Answer (score 0):

MapQuest's Transit & Date/Time Routing "gives the user the ability to specify the time and date of a route, thus compensating for lanes that are HOV at specific times, timed-turned restrictions, and seasonal or specific day of the week closures." It does not account for specific time and date historic traffic. It works great for timed traffic restrictions though.

Comment: I am aware of that description, but I'd expect that the HOV lane restrictions would be different considering I'm looking at middle of rush hour vs. midday Saturday.

Comment: Could it be that MapQuest doesn't have such specific data for this area?

Comment: I tried it again using a route that I know has HOV lanes that are restricted on Tuesday at that time, and not on Saturday, and still get the same response for both requests.

Comment: Does the 55455 to 55113 route use the time restricted lane?

Comment: No, I used different points for that. I did some more testing, and there is sometimes a difference when I enable `useTraffic` compared to when I disable it. However if `useTraffic` is enabled in both requests where I select different times, nothing changes when I believe it should.

Comment: You say it works great for timed traffic restrictions, are you able to post an example request and response that shows when it does work?

Comment: This is an extreme example, but here's one that works great at 5:30 am but breaks at 7:30 am (a bug that will be fixed in a future update).

http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/route?key=KEY&timeType=2&dateType=3&localTime=05%3A30&doReverseGeocode=false&from=40.719469,-73.999462&to=40.746954,-73.995367

http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/route?key=KEY&timeType=2&dateType=3&localTime=12%3A30&doReverseGeocode=false&from=40.719469,-73.999462&to=40.746954,-73.995367

Comment: I am using the route matrix, not the route package. I ran the matrix with these settings, and 0530 and 1230 are still the same. Are the time/date parameters only for the route package, not the matrix?

Comment: Sorry, that's correct, the matrix only does base time, not traffic or time influenced routing. It's a simplified route algorithm to keep the response time reasonable.

Comment: Strange, because I found that toggling "useTraffic" does affect the data. Is there any sort of official documentation that answers this?

Comment: Do you have a sample of a route matrix where userTraffic affects the output? I'd like to send this on to the development team to take a look. Thanks!